# interprocedural analysis

Tags: gcc, gfortran

Does gcc (C, C++ and Fortran compilers in particular) support interprocedural analysis to improve performance?
If yes, which are the relevant flags?

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InterProcedural says the gcc is going to implement IPA, but that page is quite outdated.

Comment: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it supports. Take a look at options started with -fipa [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). Recent gfortran version (4.5+) supports even more sophisticated type of optimization - link-time optimization (LTO) which is interprocedural optimizations across files. The corresponding compiler flag is -flto.

P.S. I wrote a small series of posts [about LTO](http://kemiisto.ru/2011/09/gcc-lto-1-introduction/) at my blog. You're welcome! :-)